# pagina com get de busca não esta sendo exibida por causa do REQUEST_URI

Tags: request, uri

Bom vou tentar passar o que acontece!

Possuo um site em php onde possui o arquivo config.php com as seguintes linhas

```
<?php
$current_page_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$part_url = explode("/", $current_page_uri);
$page_name = end($part_url);
$email_id = "email@email.com.br";
?>
```

Na página index.php a seguinte configuração

```
<?php 
include "app/config.php";
include "app/detect.php";

if ($page_name=='') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='index.php') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='sobre.php') {
    include $browser_t.'/sobre.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='galeria.php') {
    include $browser_t.'/galeria.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='servicos.php') {
    include $browser_t.'/servicos.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='contato.php') {
    include $browser_t.'/contato.php';
}
elseif ($page_name=='contato-post.php') {
    include $browser_t.'/contato.php';
    include 'app/contato.php';
}

else
{
    include $browser_t.'/404.html';
}

?>
```

Quando Entro nas páginas normais como `about.php`, `galeria.php` o browser abre normalmente.

Já na parte da `http://localhost/meusite/galeria.php` tenho um problema, ali é apresentada todas as fotos dos produtos que vem do Mysql, e tem uma paginação para avançar os produtos nas páginas.

Quando eu seleciono para avançar uma página de produtos no qual o link pega a referência da página que está, exemplo `http://localhost/meusite/galeria.php?pagina=2` o site não abre.

Se eu inserir no index.php a linha abaixo ele funciona.

```
elseif ($page_name=='galeria.php?pagina=2') {
    include $browser_t.'/galeria.php';
}
```

Só que tenho um problema também no botão de busca do site que pode pesquisar o produto, quando pesquiso por exemplo produto de código : "6554"

quando clico em buscar teria que abrir a página `http://localhost/meusite/galeria_busca.php?id=6554&busca=`

só que não abre também, mas como teste inseri a seguinte linha no index.php e funcionou.

```
elseif ($page_name=='galeria_busca.php?id=6554&busca=') {
    include $browser_t.'/galeria_busca.php';
}
```

Gostaria da ajuda de alguém para me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado que não esta abrindo normalmente sem precisar colocar os caminhos de busca no index.php porque tenho muitos produtos e seria inviável criar uma linha de código para cada código de produto.

Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição.

Comment: Você pega a parte final da url `http://localhost/meusite/galeria.php?pagina=2` e atribui a variável  `$page_name` que assume o valor `galeria.php?pagina=2` e depois compara isso a `galeria.php` , claro que não vai funcionar, isso é, não vai haver o `include $browser_t.'/galeria.php';` É isso que estás fazendo de errado!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Você pega a parte final da url `http://localhost/meusite/galeria.php?pagina=2` e atribui a variável `$page_name` que assume o valor `galeria.php?pagina=2` e depois compara isso a `galeria.php` , claro que não vai funcionar, isto é, não vai haver o `include $browser_t.'/galeria.php';` **É isso que estás fazendo de errado!!**

Na `$page_name = end($part_url);` veja se há o `?`, se houver faça um explode e pegue a primeira parte e atribua a variável `$page_name`

> Uma forma mais direta é fazer uso de [**strstr**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strstr.php) - encontra a primeira ocorrência de uma string

```
}elseif (strstr($page_name,"galeria.php")){
```

[**exemplo ideone**](https://ideone.com/j8FGjB)

---

---

Sobre seu comentário `..... na minha .config não tem o "?" .....`

> Quando vc acessa `http://localhost/meusite/galeria.php?pagina=2` ai tem o `?` e a sua `.config` vai te retornar `galeria.php?pagina=2` e portanto não vai entrar no `elseif ($page_name=='galeria.php') {` porque `$page_name` (que assumiu o valor `galeria.php?pagina=2`)  é diferente de `galeria.php`

---

---

**Eu descartaria a `.config` e faria da seguinte forma:**

```
<?php 
$current_page_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$email_id = "email@email.com.br";
include "app/detect.php";

if (strstr($current_page_uri,"index.php'")){
    include $browser_t.'/index.php';
}
elseif (strstr($current_page_uri,"sobre.php")){
    include $browser_t.'/sobre.php';
}
elseif (strstr($current_page_uri,"galeria.php")){
    include $browser_t.'/galeria.php';
}
elseif (strstr($current_page_uri,"servicos.php")){
    include $browser_t.'/servicos.php';
}
elseif (strstr($current_page_uri,"contato.php")){
    include $browser_t.'/contato.php';
}
elseif (strstr($current_page_uri,"contato-post.php")){
    include $browser_t.'/contato.php';
    include 'app/contato.php';
}
else
{
include $browser_t.'/404.html';
}
?>
```

Comment: Boa noite, mas não consegui compreender o que quis dizer, na minha  .config não tem o "?" está assim.

$current_page_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$part_url = explode("/", $current_page_uri);
$page_name = end($part_url);

Comment: @AlexSousa, quando vc acessa `http://localhost/meusite/galeria.php?pagina=2` ai tem o `?` e  a sua  `.config` vai te retornar `galeria.php?pagina=2`

Comment: Bom voltando aqui agora destrinchando o código pude entender o que estava errado, e para funcionar no meu config criei outra linha de código  fazendo um explode no "?" e usando o "strstr" como o @LeoCaracciolo me disse, dai no meu index.php inseri um elseif com a condição. Obrigado Leo pela ajuda.